# How to print JSON data with Perl without using JSON module?

Tags: mysql, json, perl

I am trying to write auto-complete for my dictionary project hosted on SourceForge.
Unfortunately, Perl on SF does not have JSON module installed. How can I workaround this, without using module itself? As a model I took [JQuery UI automcomplete guide on jensbits](http://www.jensbits.com/2011/05/09/jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget-with-perl-and-mysql/.).

Here is Perl code that is supposed to query text and send to the auto-complete module

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use CGI;
use DBI;
use JSON;
# HTTP HEADER 
print "Content-type: application/json; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n";

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database;mysql_read_default_file=/path/.my.cnf");

$dbh->do("set character set utf8");
$dbh->do("set names utf8");

my ($p, $sth, @query_output); 

$p = new CGI;
my $term = $p->param('term');

$sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT trim(both char(13) FROM article) AS value, definition FROM dict WHERE article like ?;});
$sth->execute('%'.$term.'%');

# LOOP THROUGH RESULTS
while ( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_hashref ){
push @query_output, $row;
}
#CLOSE THE DATABASE CONNECTION
$dbh->disconnect()
# JSON OUTPUT
print JSON::to_json(\@query_output);
```

Comment: You can always copy & paste the source of a pure Perl module in your program. Plus, if you can upload files to a server, you can use modules. See also perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html

Comment: Btw, you expect from DB UTF-8 encoded data but your HTTP-header for JSON is set to iso-8859-1. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, `JSON` package doesn't need to be installed in system.
You can just download [latest JSON distribution](http://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/M/MA/MAKAMAKA/JSON-2.53.tar.gz), unpack, upload it to your hosting and let Perl know, where to grab the code: just add

```
use lib '/absolute/path/to/JSON/lib';
```

before

```
use JSON;
```

If you don't know absolute path or want to make the code more portable, you can use [FindBin](https://metacpan.org/module/FindBin) package, to find JSON distro dir relative to your binary:

```
use FindBin
use lib "$FindBin::Bin/JSON/lib";
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Works on my laptop, but not on SF. May be something with permissions. Need to check this.

Comment: @user278192 make sure you wrote path to JSON right and add "/lib" at the end. Also I'm not 100% sure about FindBin if SF uses mod_perl or something like that.

Answer (score 7):

Why not install the module into your user directory on SourceForge using [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/module/local%3a%3alib)?

Comment: "Did not work" isn't really a useful report. If you told us what the  problem is, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 3):

If you really can't install the [`JSON`](http://perldoc.perl.org/JSON.html) module, it's not hard to write a bare-bones JSON encoder yourself:

```perl
sub to_json {
    my $val = shift;
    if (not defined $val) {
        return "null";
    } elsif (not ref $val) {
        $val =~ s/([\0-\x1f\"\\])/sprintf "\\u%04x", ord $1/eg;
        return '"' . $val . '"';
    } elsif (ref $val eq 'ARRAY') {
        return '[' . join(',', map to_json($_), @$val) . ']';
    } elsif (ref $val eq 'HASH') {
        return '{' . join(',', map to_json($_) . ":" . to_json($val->{$_}), sort keys %$val) . '}';
    } else {
        die "Cannot encode $val as JSON!\n";
    }
}
print to_json($data);
```

This code will encode `undef` as `null`, arrayrefs as JSON arrays, hashrefs as JSON objects, and *all* defined non-reference scalars as JSON strings.  It will die if it encounters anything else; notably, it doesn't map `\1` and `\0` to `true` and `false` like the `JSON` module does, although this would be easy to add if desired.

---

As an alternative, [`Data::Dumper`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) can be made to emit something approximating JSON by setting the appropriate options:

```perl
use Data::Dumper ();
print Data::Dumper->new([ $data ])->Pair(':')->Terse(1)->Useqq(1)->Deepcopy(1)->Dump();
```

However, the resulting output may not be 100% valid JSON; in particular, even with these options, `Data::Dumper`'s handling of `undef` and of strings containing special or unprintable characters does not fully match the JSON spec.

Comment: I think you also need $Data::Dumper::Useqq, as JSON parsers don't accept single quotes as string delimiters.